# Store model parameters in class as dictionaries and modify/add values

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I am running a set of different machine learning models and I want to create an object that can be sent throughout the code where things such as model parameters and directories are stored like this:

```
class model_parameters(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flags = {'clean': True,
                      'sampling': True}
        self.dirs  = {'inputs': '/inputs/',
                      'features': '/features/'}
```

Most of these parameters are constant, but some I need to modify while running the code and for some dictionaries I also add values. I am not proficient enough with object-oriented programming to say first of all if this is the best way to go about this, and secondly how I would modify values,

for example change value of `dirs['features']` to `'/features/reduced/'`,

or adding values, for example to `dirs` add the key `'labels': '/labels/'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this approach is an OK way of doing it, but unless `model_parameters` adds more information than this, I'd use a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which better conveys what you are doing:

```
from collections import namedtuple

ModelParameters = namedtuple('ModelParameters', ['flags', 'dirs'])

model_parameters = ModelParameters(flags={'clean': True,
                                          'sampling': True},
                                   dirs={'inputs': '/inputs/',
                                         'features': '/features/'})
```

You can then modify values like this:

```
model_parameters.dirs['features'] = '/features/reduced/'
```

Likewise, adding values is done by assigning to a previously unassigned key:

```
model_parameters.dirs['labels'] = '/labels/'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! I had never heard of this type. I believe I need to dig deeper into the different ways of storing in Python.